# HTML取得が途中までしか行われない

Tags: java, android

下記URLをブラウザのソースコード表示で表示すると `</html>`で終了します。
https://lp-trace.nittsu.co.jp/web/webarpaa702.srv?LANG=JP&denpyoNo1=472-05-034-0355

しかし、下記のコードで取得すると、本文途中までしか取得できません。

どのように改善すればHTMLの最後まで取得できるでしょうか。

どうかよろしくお願い致します。

```
public class AsyncHttpRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Activity mActivity;

    public AsyncHttpRequest(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "Shift_JIS"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line);
            is.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        //取得したHTMLを出力
        //sb

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

呼び出し元

```
new AsyncHttpRequest(self).execute("https://lp-trace.nittsu.co.jp/web/webarpaa702.srv?LANG=JP&denpyoNo1=472-05-034-0355");
```

Comment: コネクションログを調べてみた所、リクエストヘッダに Accept-Language を追加すると全て読み込みます。Java プログラムではなく、curl コマンドで `curl -H 'Accept-Language: ja' 'https://lp-trace.nittsu.co.jp/...'` として確認しました。

Comment: ご指摘いただいたリクエストヘッダーにAccept-Languageを追加したところ期待通りの動作になりました。ありがとうございました。追加したコード：```connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().toString());```